# Fullcalendar : AgendaDay view, hide all except axis

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to show only the axis of agenda day view.

I know how to do the inverse (.fc-axis display none) but not this...

Any solution ?

Ty

Comment: Can you post an image of the desired result? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        .... YOUR SETTINGS ....
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        allDaySlot: false
    });
```

CSS:

```
.fc-toolbar {
    display: none !important;
}
.fc-day-header {
    display: none !important;
}
```